# ViewPager2 inside a fragment leaks after replacing the fragment it's in by Navigation Component navigate

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-leaks, android-architecture-navigation, android-viewpager2

At first, i had the issue for `ViewPager2` inside a tab of `BottomNavigationView` and data binding , data binding also leaks with `ViewPager2` and should be nulled in `onDestroyView`, leaking and managed to narrow the issue to `ViewPager2` while navigating from fragment that contains ViewPager2 to another fragment using `findNavController().navigate`.

Here is how it occurs, it occurs when i navigate to another fragment that replaces the current one with ViewPager2.

[image: Memory Leak ViewPager2]

Here is the code

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**nav_graph.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph_parent"
    app:startDestination="@id/parent_dest">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/parent_dest"
        android:name="com.smarttoolfactory.tutorial6_7navigationui_memoryleakcheck.viewpagerfragment.ViewPagerContainerFragment"
        android:label="MainFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_viewpager_container">

        <!-- Login -->
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_main_dest_to_loginFragment2"
            app:destination="@id/loginFragment2" />
    </fragment>

    <!-- Login -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/loginFragment2"
        android:name="com.smarttoolfactory.tutorial6_7navigationui_memoryleakcheck.blankfragment.LoginFragment2"
        android:label="LoginFragment2"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login2"/>

</navigation>
```

Fragment that contains `ViewPager2` and `TabLayout`

```
class ViewPagerContainerFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_viewpager_container, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        // ViewPager2
        val viewPager = view.findViewById<ViewPager2>(R.id.viewPager)

        /*
            Set Adapter for ViewPager inside this fragment using this Fragment,
            more specifically childFragmentManager as param
         */
        viewPager.adapter = ChildFragmentStateAdapter(this)

        // TabLayout
        val tabLayout = view.findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.tabLayout)

        // Bind tabs and viewpager
        TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager) { tab, position ->
            when (position) {
                0 -> tab.text = "Home"
                1 -> tab.text = "Dashboard"
                2 -> tab.text = "Notification"
                3 -> tab.text = "Login"
            }
        }.attach()
    }
}
```

**fragment_viewpager_container**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayout" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Nothing special with fragments but i add one of the layouts, maybe Material widgets are leaking, i don't know

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorHome1"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Home Fragment1"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnNextPage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next Page"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvTitle" />
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And heap dump from Leak Canary

```
┬───
│ GC Root: System class
│
├─ android.app.ActivityThread class
│    Leaking: NO (MainActivity↓ is not leaking and a class is never leaking)
│    ↓ static ActivityThread.sCurrentActivityThread
├─ android.app.ActivityThread instance
│    Leaking: NO (MainActivity↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ ActivityThread.mTopActivityClient
├─ android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord instance
│    Leaking: NO (MainActivity↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord.activity
├─ com.smarttoolfactory.tutorial6_7navigationui_memoryleakcheck.MainActivity instance
│    Leaking: NO (NavHostFragment↓ is not leaking and Activity#mDestroyed is false)
│    ↓ MainActivity.mFragments
├─ androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController instance
│    Leaking: NO (NavHostFragment↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ FragmentController.mHost
├─ androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks instance
│    Leaking: NO (NavHostFragment↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.mFragmentManager
├─ androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl instance
│    Leaking: NO (NavHostFragment↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ FragmentManagerImpl.mPrimaryNav
├─ androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment instance
│    Leaking: NO (ViewPagerContainerFragment↓ is not leaking and Fragment#mFragmentManager is not null)
│    ↓ NavHostFragment.mChildFragmentManager
├─ androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl instance
│    Leaking: NO (ViewPagerContainerFragment↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ FragmentManagerImpl.mFragmentStore
├─ androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore instance
│    Leaking: NO (ViewPagerContainerFragment↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ FragmentStore.mActive
├─ java.util.HashMap instance
│    Leaking: NO (ViewPagerContainerFragment↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ HashMap.table
├─ java.util.HashMap$Node[] array
│    Leaking: NO (ViewPagerContainerFragment↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ HashMap$Node[].[0]
├─ java.util.HashMap$Node instance
│    Leaking: NO (ViewPagerContainerFragment↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ HashMap$Node.value
├─ androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager instance
│    Leaking: NO (ViewPagerContainerFragment↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ FragmentStateManager.mFragment
├─ com.smarttoolfactory.tutorial6_7navigationui_memoryleakcheck.viewpagerfragment.ViewPagerContainerFragment instance
│    Leaking: NO (Fragment#mFragmentManager is not null)
│    ↓ ViewPagerContainerFragment.mLifecycleRegistry
│                                 ~~~~~~
├─ androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ LifecycleRegistry.mObserverMap
│                        ~~~~
├─ androidx.arch.core.internal.FastSafeIterableMap instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ FastSafeIterableMap.mEnd
│                          ~~
├─ androidx.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap$Entry instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ SafeIterableMap$Entry.mKey
│                            ~~
├─ androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter$FragmentMaxLifecycleEnforcer$3 instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Anonymous class implementing androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleEventObserver
│    ↓ FragmentStateAdapter$FragmentMaxLifecycleEnforcer$3.this$1
│                                                          ~~
├─ androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter$FragmentMaxLifecycleEnforcer instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ FragmentStateAdapter$FragmentMaxLifecycleEnforcer.mViewPager
│                                                        ~~~~
├─ androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2 instance
│    Leaking: YES (View detached and has parent)
│    mContext instance of com.smarttoolfactory.tutorial6_7navigationui_memoryleakcheck.MainActivity with mDestroyed = false
│    View#mParent is set
│    View#mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
│    View.mID = R.id.viewPager
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
│    ↓ ViewPager
```

I also add [github link](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/NavigationComponents-Tutorials/tree/master/Tutorial6-7NavigationUI-MemoryLeakCheck) if you wish to check for yourself or recreate the issue.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Removing adapter from ViewPager2 in `onDestroyView` method of fragment solved the memory leak issue with `FragmentStateAdapter`

```
 override fun onDestroyView() {

        val viewPager2 = dataBinding?.viewPager

        viewPager2?.let {
            it.adapter = null
        }
        super.onDestroyView()
 }
```

Also set data binding to null in `onDestroyView` of fragment, i did it in base fragment, which was causing data binding related memory leak. Or use it as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding?hl=hr#fragments) for viewBinding, it applies to data binding.

```
private var _binding: ResultProfileBinding? = null
// This property is only valid between onCreateView and
// onDestroyView.
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    _binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val view = binding.root
    return view
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
```

> Note: Fragments outlive their views. Make sure you clean up any
> references to the binding class instance in the fragment's
> onDestroyView() method.

Another thing to prevent memory leaks with `ViewPager2` inside a fragment is to use `viewLifeCycleOwner`'s lifeCycle which is between `onCreateView` and `onDestroyView` instead of `this` with FragmentStateAdapter as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62184494/5457853).

```
FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
Lifecycle lifecycle = getViewLifecycleOwner().getLifecycle();
fragmentAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(fm, lifecycle);
```

Comment: The last part saved me. Tried set `binding = null` `adapter = null` both not works. Only the last works, thanks!